# Multiple markers on google maps using json and placeid

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

the problem i've got is that I don't know where the problem is :P
From the beginning. I've got 3 files, the json file JS and html. JS should get placeid from json and based on that place a marker on the map. It's all pretty simple but somehow it doesn't work, the map is being created but no markers show up.
Here're the files:

JSON:

```
       [{   "placeid":   'ChIJu6HrLMVWIkcRWHTA90kiueI'              ,           "content":  "   1   "   }   ,
        {   "placeid":    'ChIJnXBuJ34zGUcRvt9FTKrPeeM'             ,           "content":  "   2   "   }   ,
        {   "placeid":    'ChIJiwUNhqX7PEcRdJjYqzrWYjs'             ,           "content":  "   3   "   }   ]
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="functions_edit.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var openedInfoWindow = null;

function initialize() {
        var latitude = 51.9315631,
            longitude = 19.473451,
            radius = 8000, 
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
            mapOptions = {
                center: center,
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: false
            };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(center, radius, map);
    }

    function setMarkers(center, radius, map) {
        var json = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({ 
                'async': false, 
                'global': false, 
                'url': "placeid.json", 
                'dataType': "json", 
                'success': function (data) {
                     json = data; 
                 }
            });
            return json;
        })();


        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i];

                                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.getDetails({
                    placeId: data.placeid
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            alert(status);
            return;
        }
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        place: {
                            placeId: data.placeid,
                            location: result.geometry.location
                        }
                        //position: result.geometry.location
                    });
                });

                infoBox(map, marker, data);
            }
        }

    function infoBox(map, marker, data) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {

            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        (function(marker, data) {

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {

            infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        })(marker, data);
    }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the posted code I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`

You are calling the `InfoBox` function in the wrong place (outside the scope where `marker` exists).

Once I fix that I get infowindows, but you have an issue that can be solved by function closure (all the infowindows have the content "3", the last marker processed).  (For an example of function closure see [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example))

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2tryL5Lk/22/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var placeid_json = [{
    "placeid": 'ChIJu6HrLMVWIkcRWHTA90kiueI',
    "content": "   1   "
}, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJnXBuJ34zGUcRvt9FTKrPeeM',
    "content": "   2   "
}, {
    "placeid": 'ChIJiwUNhqX7PEcRdJjYqzrWYjs',
    "content": "   3   "
}];


var openedInfoWindow = null;

function initialize() {
    var latitude = 51.9315631,
        longitude = 19.473451,
        radius = 8000,
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapOptions = {
            center: center,
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    setMarkers(center, radius, map);
}

function setMarkers(center, radius, map) {
    /* var json = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({ 
                'async': false, 
                'global': false, 
                'url': "placeid.json", 
                'dataType': "json", 
                'success': function (data) {
                     json = data; 
                 }
            });
            return json;
        })(); */

    var json = placeid_json;
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
        var data = json[i];
        createMarker(data, map);
    }
}
function createMarker(data, map) {
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: data.placeid
        }, function (result, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                alert(status);
                return;
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                place: {
                    placeId: data.placeid,
                    location: result.geometry.location
                }
                //position: result.geometry.location
            });
            infoBox(map, marker, data, result);
        });

}
function infoBox(map, marker, data, result) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

        infoWindow.setContent(data.content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    (function (marker, data) {

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

            infoWindow.setContent(data.content+"<br>"+result.name);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(marker, data);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
```